# Better way to catch the state of my action in my app + react-redux +react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-state

I create an example to use react-redux in my app that is working and print the value of my test, my doubt here is exist other way to catch the state of the store and don't write the code `login[0].user` to catch the value of the reduce that i will save.

thanks to all

File:: APP

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from '../pages/Login'
import NotFound from '../pages/404'

const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props}/>}  />
            <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
export default App
```

File login

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
const Login = (...login) => {
  console.log("value before")
  console.log(login)
  const loginUser = login[0].user;
  console.log("valor after")
  console.log(loginUser)

}

const mapStateProps = (state)=>{
  return{
    user: state.loginUser,
  };

}
const wrapper = connect(mapStateProps);
const component = wrapper (Login);

export default component
```

File store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import loginUser from './Redux/reducer/loginUser'

const reducer =combineReducers({loginUser})
const store = createStore(reducer)

export default store
```

File Reducer

```
const defautlState={username:'test',password:'test'};

function reducer(state= defautlState,{type,payload}){
    switch(type){
        case 'saveSession':{
            return {
                username:'test2',
                password:'test2'
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default reducer;
```

File Action creator

```
export const type = 'saveSession'

const saveSession = user =>{
    return {
        type,
        payload:user,
    };

};

export default saveSession;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you need `login[0]` is because of the way that you have defined `Login` here:

```
const Login = (...login) => {
```

The `...` means that `login` is an array of [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and that your `Login` component can take any number of arguments.  This isn't right because React components can only take one argument which is a `object` of props.

You want to define it like this:

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const user = props.user;
  // rest of the component
}
```

Or you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the arguments:

```
const Login = ({user}) => {
  // rest of the component
}
```

You could also take no arguments and get the value of `user` from [`useSelector`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) instead of [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const Login = () => {
  const user = useSelector( state => state.loginUser );
  // rest of the component
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Yes is working, I don't know why when I try the `const Login = (props) => { ...}` show me a message that props is undifined mmm, thanks a lot and the three ways are working.